# How do I stop nodejs app from failing when res.json() is called?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, routes

I want to check if email ID already exists in MongoDB. When if req.body.email is set then it would fire a MongoDB query and if result is true then it should send status:true in json.

I have tried sending res.json() from outside User.findOne() still it did not work. I have set Accept header to application/json. Still not working.

Code at NodeJS

```
router.post("/individual/signup", (req, res, next) => {
    let isJSON = false;
    if (req.body.email) {
        let email = req.body.email.toLowerCase().trim()
        User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, result) => {
            if (result) {
                return res.json({status: true}).end()
            } else {
                return res.json({status: false}).end()
            }
        })
    } else {
        return res.json({ status: false }).end()
    }
})
```

Code in front end

```
fetch('/individual/signup', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: "ishwar@gmail.com"
    })
}).then(function (res) {
    return res.json()
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log("received data: " + JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

error log

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle codex-app@0.0.0~prestart: codex-app@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle codex-app@0.0.0~start: codex-app@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle codex-app@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle codex-app@0.0.0~start: PATH: <long path value>;
9 verbose lifecycle codex-app@0.0.0~start: CWD: E:\Projects\codex-app
10 silly lifecycle codex-app@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./bin/start' ]
11 silly lifecycle codex-app@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle codex-app@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: codex-app@0.0.0 start:`node ./bin/start
`13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid codex-app@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd E:\Projects\codex-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.0.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error codex-app@0.0.0 start:`node ./bin/start
`22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the codex-app@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

It should either return {status: true} if found else {status: false}

Comment: Are your backend and front end running on different ports

Comment: FYI, `res.json()` should not be followed with `.end()`.  It sends a request all on its own.  I don't know if that's related to your issue or not.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  What exactly  happens in the client and server?  Also, I'd suggest you put a `.catch()` handler on your `fetch()` and you specifically log `err` on your database call.  If you're getting an error back from the `fetch()`, you will do nothing.

Comment: @Sathiraumesh no. Same ports. Communication is proper.

Comment: @jfriend00 no change. The app still exits with
`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1`

Comment: Can you please post the error stack?

Comment: @jfriend00 The MongoDB returns an object. Nothing wrong with query. But when res.anymethod is called the app exits.

Comment: Exits with what error?  Remove the `.end()` from all your `res.json()` calls in Express.  That could be causing the problem.  `.end()` is used with `res.write()`, not with `res.json()` and not with `res.send()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I removed all `.end()` but problem still exists. I have add debug log in my question. Please check. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't recognize that error log as having anything to do with the code you show.  Can you execute your server startup script in just a plain node app without the lifecycle stuff and capture just a plain node.js log?

Comment: Maybe there were some error when you install node library. Try clean cache, remove node modules and install again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to clean cache then delete node_modules, delete package-lock.json and then npm install

`npm cache clean --force && rm -rf node_modules && rm ./package-lock.json && npm install`